# Trying to perform a slightly different search (Timer, event listener, event dispatch?)

Tags: javascript

**How I need to:**

1. First keyup on (search input) fires up search countdown timer and set timer to 1s.
2. Every next search keyup on (search input) reset search countdown timer to 1s.
3. When (search input) no longer updated and stay the same -
4. Search countdown timer reached 0s and performing a search.

**Why I need to (this way):**

I have large database of records and using ajax method to fetch through. Every time keyup on (search input) send a request... (it's resource waste and uncomfortable to watch how page refresh every keyup). So my way is to create **"typing phase"** - what I mean describe above.

**Only **pure JS**, no libraries! Thanks.**

Comment: `Only pure JS, no libraries! ` Ok and what have you tried? StackOverflow is not a code writing service so need to show what your attempt of solving the problem ist and explain what the problem with your solution is.

Comment: What you need is called debounce function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var timer=null;
document.getElementById("myInput").onkeyup = ()=>{
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(()=>{
            console.log("call ajax search function here."); 
            clearInterval(timer);
          },1000);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput">
```

Comment: I can't believe it's so simple, maybe I'am to tired of work. Very thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it was useful to you.

Comment: One more question, why in event listener (keyup) setInterval do not repeat itself again ? (What stop him ?) Just curious, can't understand logic. Example if i use setTimeout inside event listener it will repeat itself as much time as I release a key.

Comment: every time you press a key and it fires keyup, the timer is cleared by `clearInterval(timer);` which I called in the first line of the event. after that, it sets a new timer Interval. if you repeat typing before the ending interval, it will be cleared again. until you stop typing and the function in the timer will be fired. after logging on console, I've called `clearInterval(timer);` again to avoid repeating it.

Comment: Now I get it. AWESOME :)

Answer (score 0):

what you need is called debounce function.

if you don't use libraries like lodash - you can take this realisation:

```
function debounce(f, ms) {

  let isCooldown = false;

  return function() {
    if (isCooldown) return;

    f.apply(this, arguments);

    isCooldown = true;

    setTimeout(() => isCooldown = false, ms);
  };

}
```

then you can code like this:

```
const handleSearch = (search) => {
    // your logic with fetch or whatever
}

const handleSearchDebounced = debounce(handleSearch, 300)
```

Comment: If you copy and past parts of the question (like code) from somewhere you should quote where you got it from.

Comment: mahdi gholami answer was so simple and works very well. BUT i have more issues in other places and your suggestion about "debounce" function is very interesting and helpfull. Thanks.